# Checking a given proof.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $\textbf{S}$ and $\textbf{T}$ are two collections of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, then $\sigma (\textbf{S})$ the smallest $\sigma-$ algebra that contains $\textbf{S}$ and $\sigma (\textbf{T})$ the smallest $\sigma-$ algebra that contains $\textbf{T}$.\

Distinguish between 2 cases:\

Case(I). $S \cap T = \emptyset.$\

Then, $S \cap T \in \sigma(\textbf{S}) \cap \sigma (\textbf{T}).$ Because each $\sigma-$algebra contains the empty set as the empty union equals the empty set and the $\sigma-$algebra is closed with respect to the formation of countable unions.\newline
And hence $\sigma(S \cap T) \subset \sigma(\textbf{S}) \cap \sigma (\textbf{T})$.As $\sigma(S \cap T)$ is the smallest sigma algebra that contains $S \cap T.$Note that $\sigma(S \cap T)$ is  the trivial $\sigma-$algebra in this case $i.e.\sigma(S \cap T) = \{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}$.

Case(II). $S \cap T \neq \emptyset.$\

Let $E \in S \cap T,$ then $E \in \sigma(\textbf{S})$ and $E \in \sigma(\textbf{T}).$ which means $ E \in \subset \sigma(\textbf{S}) \cap \sigma (\textbf{T}).$
$$i.e. S \cap T \subset \sigma(\textbf{S}) \cap \sigma (\textbf{T}). $$

But  $\sigma(S \cap T)$ is the smallest sigma algebra that contains $S \cap T.$ Then $$\sigma(S \cap T) \subset \sigma(\textbf{S}) \cap \sigma (\textbf{T})$$

**My question is:**

I know that the last line in my argument in $Case(II)$ "But  $\sigma(S \cap T)$ is the smallest sigma-algebra that contains $S \cap T.$ Then $$\sigma(S \cap T) \subset \sigma(\textbf{S}) \cap \sigma (\textbf{T})$$" is incorrect as an example the Borel sets and sigma-algebra of the open sets (**I was given this example by a professor but I did not fully understand it, so could anyone explain this for me also?)**,Also, could anyone find the mistakes in my proof and give me an elegant and simpler proof than this, please?

Comment: Why do you think that statement in case ii is incorrect?  The comment about the borels v the open sets doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: @BrianMoehring my professor said that this is incorrect and he gave me the example I mentioned

Comment: he\she   said that the statement before your last statement leads to $$\sigma ( S \cap T) \subset \sigma(\sigma(\textbf{S}) \cap \sigma (\textbf{T})). $$ instead @BrianMoehring

Comment: Frankly speaking, I did not get his\her point of view.@BrianMoehring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, it sounds like your professor is critiquing your justification rather than saying your statement is incorrect.  You either need to re-write your justification or simply justify the additional step of $$\sigma(\sigma(S) \cap \sigma(T)) = \sigma(S) \cap \sigma(T)$$

As for your request of a simpler proof... the acceptable justification for homework depends on what theorems have been proven for you to use, which is something I don't know.  However, based on the professor's comments, it would seem you can at least use
$$X\subseteq Y \implies \sigma(X) \subseteq \sigma(Y)$$

In this case, the typical proof of the statement you're proving would just be
$$\left.\begin{array}{c}S \cap T \subseteq S \implies \sigma(S \cap T) \subseteq \sigma(S) \\ S \cap T \subseteq T \implies \sigma(S \cap T) \subseteq \sigma(T)\end{array}\quad\right\}\implies \sigma(S\cap T) \subseteq \sigma(S) \cap \sigma(T)$$

Comment: But why $$\sigma(\sigma(S) \cap \sigma(T)) = \sigma(S) \cap \sigma(T)$$?

Comment: @hopefully This follows from two basic facts:  (1) If $\mathcal{A}$ is a sigma-algebra, then $\sigma(\mathcal{A}) = \mathcal{A}$ .... and (2) If $\mathcal{A}_1, \mathcal{A}_2$ are sigma algebras over a common set, then $\mathcal{A}_1 \cap \mathcal{A}_2$ is a sigma algebra. ....  You should prove both these if they need proof (it may be that (1) is your definition of a sigma algebra, in which case it doesn't need proof)

Comment: you mean by the points that the sigma algebra of $A$ contains other elements than $A$...... correct?

Comment: @hopefully I don't understand your question.

Comment: I am speaking about the dots in your first comment.

Comment: If you're talking about the four periods in a row (as in  .... ), that was just for separation since I was listing two theorems and didn't want to mix them up.  If I were able to easily create new lines in a comment, I would have done that instead.  Needless to say, if that's what your confusion is about, then I obviously failed to make it more readable...

Comment: No ..... I mean in your first comment after saying that $\sigma (A) = A$ ..... you put 4 dots ...... are you saying that $\sigma (A) = A$ only?

Comment: I refer you to my previous comment.   They were used for nothing but separation.  Here are the two theorems again without the confounding periods/dots/points/full stops/whatever: $$\text{If } \mathcal{A} \text{ is a sigma-algebra, then } \sigma(\mathcal{A}) = \mathcal{A}$$ $$\text{If } \mathcal{A}_1, \mathcal{A}_2 \text{ are sigma-algebras over a common set, then } \mathcal{A}_1\cap\mathcal{A}_2 \text{ is a sigma-algebra}$$

Comment: yeah got it ...... there is a theorem saying that sigma-algebra of sigma-algebra is the set itself ..... it is like the complement?  ... this is my first time to see this theorem.

Comment: I think your justification is correct in both cases ...... correct?